# Where are the Mishnas in the Talmud?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, talmud-gemara, mishna

I'm looking for a source of data that tells me where each chapter of Mishna starts in the Talmud (Babylonian, bonus points for Jerusalem.)  (I'm looking for Vilna daf numbers, and whatever the equivalent is called in the Jerusalem Talmud.) If I can find one that tells me where each Mishna starts, that would be even better.

Anyone got anything for me?

---

Edit:
To be clear, I need *all* of them, as data, computer readable, in one place.  Printed reference doesn't do me much good.

Comment: I'd have to check to be sure, but I seem to recall that Koren references mishnayos by the Vilna daf numbers.

Comment: The breakup of Mishna in the Talmuds is different (from each other and) from the stand-alone printed Mishnayot.

Comment: @DoubleAA ... and more to the point (since the question doesn't ask about the breakup into _mishnayos_), so is the ordering of chapters.

Comment: @msh210 - Interesting!  Which chapters switch around?

Comment: @Laizer IIRC chapters of _M'nachos_ are in a different order in the _Bavli_ from their order in the _mishnayos_. I seem vaguely to recall the same is true of _P'sachim_ but I may be confusing that with some other quirk _P'sachim_ has.

Comment: You can "cheat" by learning mishna with Kehati. He will usually quote a gemara on that mishna which should give you at least an idea in terms of daf numbers. 
@msh210 I think the eighth chapter of brachos is as well.

Comment: @msh210 Also, _Challah_, _Megillah_ and _Sanhedrin_ IINM. And at the end he does ask "If I can find one that tells me where each Mishna starts, that would be even better."

Comment: Oh, I missed that last part, @DoubleAA.

Comment: Not to mention that there is no standard numbering scheme of the Yerushlami.

Comment: This sounds to me like the sort of resource that it would be fun to compile for yourself - and you'll likely learn a great deal in the process.

Comment: @DannySchoemann There are a few different ways; each is standardized though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't find a good source for this information, so we (at [Sefaria.org](http://sefaria.org)) analyzed our text, did some pattern recognition, corrected by hand, double checked, and came up with an authoritative [mapping between the Mishnah and the Babylonian Talmud](https://github.com/blockspeiser/Sefaria-Project/blob/master/data/Mishnah%20Map.csv).  Line numbers here refer to the segmentation in Sefaria's online Talmud.

Answer (score 2):

You could go to [Machon Mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/index.htm) and [download](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/dlb.htm) the entire Bavli and Yerushalmi.

They seem to have a very standardized format for highlighting when the Mishna starts and what page it's on. You can then parse the data and create this index.